# Capabilites of a Facebook Access token while user is not active

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If I give access to an app in Facebook can it retrieve/publish information from/into my profile when I'm not using that app?

Lets say I have an app with permissions to post on my timeline.And I haven't used that app any nearby, can it still post to my timeline ?(app with 60 days accesstoken granted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, an Extended User Token is valid for 60 days and you can use it during that time - even while the user is offline. Be aware that autoposting is not allowed though, and each message has to be user generated. Each and every single post must be approved and written by the user.

Comment: kk..Facebook reference says that a single user can increase the API call rate/hour of an app by 200calls/hour.So If I have 10 user's for my app then total calls that can be made by my app is 48000/day and 2000/hour ?

Comment: you really should not have any problems with rate limits, only if you are doing something you shouldn´t do. for example, to retrieve new data you should use webhooks instead of cron jobs.

Comment: @luschn.I have to use a combination of webhook & cron,the job will only be initiated by user itself,that I can guarantee ,but job needs to be cron if my app have too much concurrent calls made at same time.Will that be an issue ?

Comment: depends on the amount of calls you make, obviously. just limit those, don´t make unneccessary and too frequent calls.

Comment: @luschn.kkk If what you said is correct how can facebook identify the **average daily active users** used to implement rate limiting?Isn't facebook assuming that the app is legimate and all the calls are made by active users on their behalf ?**[reference link]**(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting)

Comment: no, how would they know that? anyway, that´s a completely different topic, and you would have to ask facebook directly about the specifics for rate limiting. rule of thumb: if you hit a limit, you are doing something you are not supposed to do ;)